# How to fill up gaps in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

My data in excel has for example the following data in columns A and B:

```
A   B

1   4
2   6
5   88
9   67
12  45
```

and so on.

I would like to transform it as following:

```
A   B

1   4
2   6
3   0
4   0
5   88
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   67
10  0
11  0
12  45
```

and so on.

What I want is to insert missing consecutive values on column A values with corresponding column B values as zeros in data.

Comment: This can be done with vba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this *with formulas* is with a helper column and [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Say in column D you print your complete list 1 through 12. Then in column E, you can use -

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE),0)
```

And drag it down.

[image]